# using .NET Assemblies in Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, assemblies, gac, regasm

I am currently required to open and use a .NET assembly in delphi.  The Assembly that i am trying to use also has an assembly of objects it is using.  With the object assembly i was able to use regasm to create a type library.  I was also able to assign a SN and register it with the GAC.

Now with the main assembly i am tyring to use in Delphi, i try using regasm and i end up getting an error "Regasm : error RA0000 : Unable to locate input assembly [location] or one of its dependencies."  I have looked over the location and file name and there is nothing wrong. Am i missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at Atozed CrossTalk http://www.atozed.com/CrossTalk/index.DE.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure all the assemblies your assembly references are in the GAC?